# Sweet alert 2 Okay go to new page cancel stay at the page how?

Tags: sweetalert2

Hi i got some problem with my sweet alert where i have redirected the user when click okay it be sent to the new page but if cancel they remain at the same page and close the alert boxhow can i do it ?

Here my code for the sweet alert

```
 Swal.fire({
                                        icon: 'success',
                                        title: 'Insert Successfully!',
                                        html: 'The information have inserted successfully!<br>By pressing <b>okay</b> this page will go to <b>manage user</b> page',
                                        showCancelButton: true,
                                        cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
                                        confirmButtonText: 'Okay',
                                        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                                        confirmButtonColor: 'btn-success',
                                        heightAuto: false,
                                        })
                                        // footer: '<label class="fixissue">How to fix this issue?</label><br>Try to change the username input and press add button again'
                                    .then(Okay => {
                                        window.location.href = 'manageUsers_api.html';

                                    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i have fix it by creating a if and else if with a value confirm

```
.then(function(inputvalue){
                                    if(inputvalue.isConfirmed){
                                        window.location.href = 'manageUsers_api.html';
                                    } else if(inputvalue.isCancel){
                                        Swal.fire('')
                                    }

                                })
```